# Regex is failing to capture values inside [...][...]

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to change color of a text in my string :

my string :

```
$message="I have a [red][car]";
```

I want to capture the values inside the first **[...]** and second **[...]** and then use it in

```
<b style='color:color'>car</b>
```

to change the text color according to the value of first **[...]**

So far I have :

```
echo preg_replace("/\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]+])\]/i","<b style='color:$1'>$2</b>",$message);
```

But it's not working, the orignal string is returned as output. I don't know where my regex failed.

Please help!

Comment: You misplaced the `]`: use `'/\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]/'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The corrected regex is:

```
'/\[([^\]]+)]\[([^\]]+)]/'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS8eX4/1)

Note that you do not have to escape `]` outside the character class and no need in `/i` modifier as there are not letters in your pattern. Also, to properly escape special regex characters, you either need to double escapes in the double quoted string, or use a single quoted string.

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/FyWLVu):

```
$message="I have a [red][car]";
echo preg_replace('/\[([^\]]+)]\[([^\]]+)]/',"<b style='color:$1'>$2</b>",$message);
// => I have a <b style='color:red'>car</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$message="I have a [red][car]";
echo preg_replace("/[^\[]+\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]/i","&lt;b style='color:$1'&gt;$2&lt;/b&gt;",$message);
```